# XmlDocument.Save() vs XDocument.Save()

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I had some XML manipulation using XmlDocument, XmlElement etc.
I replaced it with code using XDocument, XElement etc, to modernize it.
However, some inner text of an element contained character `'\x4'`.
With XmlDocument.Save() this was saved as `&#x4;` and everything worked fine, even with third-party tools. But XDocument.Save() throws

```
System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character.
  + System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(int, System.Byte*, bool)
  + System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(System.Char*, System.Char*)
  + System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteString(string)
  + System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(string)
  + System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(string)
  + System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(System.Xml.Linq.XElement)
  + System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter)
  + System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.WriteContentTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter)
  + System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter)
  + System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(string, System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions)
  + System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(string)
```

Temporarily, I used XmlConvert.EncodeName() but this converts it to `_x0004_` which will not allow to be read correcty, unless decoded with XmlConvert.DecodeName().

Can I achieve the previous saving functionality?

Minimal step:

```
    //ok
    Console.WriteLine(new XDocument(new XElement("test","aa")).ToString());
    //System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character.
    Console.WriteLine(new XDocument(new XElement("test","aa \x4")).ToString());
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tONAm6)

**EDIT:** Searching .NET Source, I found that the previous correct behavior was probably done by the private XmlTextEncoder.WriteCharEntityImpl(string). However, this class seems undocumented and I can't imagine how I could take advantage of.

Comment: @Selvin thank you  for the editing

Comment: `&#x4;` is actually [disallowed by XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets), so `XDocument.Save()` is doing the right thing. If you need to include that character in your document, you should consider either base64 encoding it (recognizing that XML is not designed to directly carry binary) or update to XML 1.1 (which allows everything but U+0—but that might not be an option for you if you need to specify 0 and almost nothing supports XML 1.1).

Answer (score -1):

I found an acceptable way of doing what I wanted, by using an XmlTextWriter for the saving, so I post it as an answer to my own question.
However, I would prefer it, if there was a solution with LINQ-to-XML only classes

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var xdoc=new XDocument(new XElement("Params", new XElement("test","aa1 \x4")));
         using (var xw = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out)
                {
                    Formatting=Formatting.Indented
                } )
                    xdoc.WriteTo(xw);   
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XL3u9R)